# Rails won't process requests via curl in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, curl

When using the browser and going to http://localhost:3000/ it works as it should

when doing

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

it returns immediately without printing the response. In the server I see

```
 Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-17 12:03:49 +0200
```

and that's it.. It seems as if the request isn't getting processed

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I was missing something obvious..

the server uses basic authentication that the browser saved, but curl didn't show any problems.

Doing `curl -i` showed a 401 error

fixed via

```
curl --user username:password http://localhost:3000/
```